# Upload images on disk and save image name on mysql DB with php

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I have a `MySQL` db, with 2 tables, albums and photos:

albums has  id and name, photos has id, album_id, photo_name.

and I have the following script:

```
<?php

$albumsQuery = $mysqli->query( "SELECT `album_id`, `album_name` FROM `albums` ORDER BY `album_name` ASC" );

if( isset( $_FILES["albumPhoto"] )  )
{
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["albumPhoto"]["tmp_name"], "photos/" .$_FILES["albumPhoto"]["name"] );
}

if( isset( $_POST["album_name"] ) )
{
    $uploadQuery = $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO `photos` ( `photo_id`, `photos`.`photo_id_album`, `photos`.`photo_name` )
    VALUES ( NULL,'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST["album_name"] ) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_FILES["albumPhoto"]["name"] ) . "' )" )
    or die( $mysqli->error );

    $upload = $uploadQuery->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
}
?>
```

The image is uploaded on disk, but I can't get the image name on DB.

Comment: Is your isset( $_POST["album_name"] ) block being called at all?

Comment: Did you try to prin $uploadQuery variable? And also check whether or not your code enter isset( $_POST["album_name"] ) block, like user1161318 said.

Comment: it seems nothing happens went I print_r ($uploadQuery) ...

Comment: Thanks a lot guys ... It seems that I did a typo when I wrote album_name... it was albumname... the name of the <select>

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code while you answered your own question so I'll just post it anyway:

```
$albumsQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT album_id, album_name FROM albums ORDER BY album_name');

// assume image not uploaded
$imagePath = null;

// if a photo is being uploaded
if (isset($_FILES["albumPhoto"])) {
    $source = $_FILES["albumPhoto"]["tmp_name"];
    $target = sprintf('photos/', $_FILES["albumPhoto"]["name"]);

    // try to move the file
    $move = move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
    if ($move !== true) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move the uploaded file: ' . $_FILES["albumPhoto"]["name"]);
    }
}

// attach the image to the specified album
if (isset($_POST["album_name"])) {
    $stmt = 'INSERT INTO photos (photo_id_album, photo_name)
             VALUES (?, ?)';
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $albumName, $photoName);

    // values of bound variables
    $albumName = $_POST["album_name"];
    $photoName = $_FILES["albumPhoto"]["name"];

    // insert the record
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Also, it's not a good idea to use the original filename as users might want to upload multiple files with the same name into the same album over the time. Consider using hashes or prepending the album id to the file name.

And add a few more error checks!